# ctrl-z is not working for Interactive Ruby in terminal window

Tags: ruby, shell, ctrl

After I use `irb` from the Windows command line, I can't get `^Z` using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to return to it.

```
irb(main):001:0> print 'hi'
hi=> nil
irb(main):002:0> ^Z
=> nil
irb(main):003:0*
irb(main):004:0*
```

It looks like I started some control sequence. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Comment: `Ctrl+z` should also work,as it is not helping you,use `exit` then...

Answer (score 1):

I think `CTRL+D` or `exit` should work.

Comment: Yeah, those work, although I'm still curious as to why ctrl+z isn't working.

Comment: This is a good question. Do you use standard windows shell or some cygwin-ish thing?

Comment: I just use the standard windows command line for this.  I've used MSYS and some MinGW64 stuff for other purposes, but I'm just using the vanilla command prompt in Windows for this.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I believe that the cause is your wrong understanding of what the control+Z actually is. It is not for "switching", but it is "suspension". Further more, such these combos are handled by the handled by the shell itself, so it's not about IRB or Ruby.

See ie. https://superuser.com/questions/476873/what-is-effect-of-ctrl-z-on-a-unix-linux-application

On Linux-like environments, control+Z is suspends its current child and 'unlinks' it from stdin/stdout (I think) so you can get back and interact with the shell again. Similarly, control+C causes the shell to send a signal to the current child, etc.

On Windows, this is simply **not implemented**. Pressing control+whatever simply sends this character to the stdin of the current application (except for two cases mentioned below). This is why pressing control+Z sends `^Z` metacharacter and this is why IRB reacts to it as if you wrote some strange thing.

Many utilities (including shells) ported from Linux environments to Windows are specifically adapted to emulate some of the behaviors. See for example: https://superuser.com/questions/580816/why-can-i-only-suspend-using-ctrl-z-in-screen-under-cygwin -- so it seems that i.e. Cygwin's console supports that.

However, the "native" console of the Windows OS does not support control+Z. It actually supports almost no combos. [According to this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682541(v=vs.85).aspx) only control+C and control+Break are supported, and they mean exactly the same. The third combo mentioned is unavailable from the keyboard and is used when the consol window is closed with standard [X] button.